# How to recover folder from previous ubuntu version

Tags: data-recovery

I had Ubuntu 13.04 version in my computer. There was a important folder in downloads. But on 10th July, I removed (not upgraded) 13.04 in my computer and installed 14.04. With this my important folder has also deleted. But I want to recover that folder. Please reply how to recover.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed new Ubuntu to the same partition as the old on, then filesystem was recreated before clean installation and - sorry - but there is no way to get it back.

If not, give some more detail about how you installed new system.

Comment: I have uninstalled/ removed totally the 13.04 and then installed again 14.04 from pendrive.  Please sir suggest some way, its important.

Comment: I really would like to help you, but I'm afraid there is nothing we can do. Maybe some specialised companies that deal with data recover, but I doubt that. It would be possible to recover data, if you only deleted partition. But after overwriting the data there is just nothing to recover.